# Spring Boot @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

Есть SpringBoot приложение, которое имеет следующую структуру:

```
project
-src
|-main
 |-java
  |-conf
   |-CommandsConfig.java
  |-app
   |-CommandsFactory.java
   |-commands
    |-Command.java
    |-FirstCommand.java
    |-SecondCommand.java
    |-ThridCommand.java
  |-Application.java
```

```
@Component
public class CommandsFactory {

  private Map<String, Command> commands;

  @Autowired
  public CommandsFactory (Map<String, Command> commands) {
    this.commands = commands;
  }

  ...
}

@Configuration
public class CommandsConfig {

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Command> commands(FirstCommand firstCommand,
                                       SecondCommand secondCommand,
                                       ThridCommand thridCommand) {
    Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap();

    commands.put("first", firstCommand);
    commands.put("secon", seconCommand);
    commands.put("thrid", thridCommand);

    return commands;
  }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

классы FirstCommand, SecondCommand,  ThridCommand реализуют интерфейс Command и переопределяют единственный метод getResult(), все аннотированы как @Component;

Проблема заключается в том, что поле Map<String, Commands> commands которое поидее должно инициализироваться бином из конфига, инициализируется иначе и при вызове commands.toString() имеет следующую структуру:

```
{firstCommand=app.commands.FirstCommand@fb2c2f3, secondCommand=app.commands.SecondCommand@w5bh7b3, thridCommand=app.commands.ThridCommand@o3ti53}
```

т.е. Map<String, Commands> commands инициализируется не так как задано в конфиге

изменял класс конфига и добавлял вывод в консоль во время инициализации бина

```
@Configuration
public class CommandsConfig {

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Command> commands(FirstCommand firstCommand,
                                       SecondCommand secondCommand,
                                       ThridCommand thridCommand) {
    Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap();

    commands.put("first", firstCommand);
    commands.put("secon", seconCommand);
    commands.put("thrid", thridCommand);

    System.out.println(commands);

    return commands;
  }
}
```

Выводит нормально инициализированный бин:

```
{first=app.commands.FirstCommand@fb2c2f3, second=app.commands.SecondCommand@w5bh7b3, thrid=app.commands.ThridCommand@o3ti53}
```

Отсюда вопросы: 1. Почему Map в классе не инициализируется бином из конфига
2. Как лучше инициализировать Map поле?

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы: необходимо было добавить @Qualifier